# Language change on iOS Device

Tags: ios, localization

What does changing the system language on a device do to applications?

In XCode, when i run an app and change the language on the simulator, the app crashes or exits.

Answer (score 1):

When a user changes the language of an iPhone, the iPhone reboots.

Comment: so how do i handle this event in my app when the user changes language?

Comment: They are literally terminated. You can do nothing. What are you trying to do?